# php printf not printing in correct order

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a website that is reading out data in a list from a database, that works but when I started to work on the styling I added a div with a class that has borders, when I tried it out it placed the new div before the ending of the other tag
Element tree: https://www.dropbox.com/s/asd2dgvcybwn9vn/Capture.PNG?dl=0

I tried using echo instead of printf and moving the last printf around a bit

```
        <?php
            $db = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

            if (!$db) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `XP` ORDER BY xp DESC";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    printf ('<div class="user">');
                    printf ('<img class="profile_pic" src="' . $row["Profile_Pic"] . '" >' . "<br>");
#                    printf ("ID: " . $row["ID"] . "<br>");
                    printf ("Nickname: " . $row["Nickname"] . "<br>");
#                    printf ("UserID: " . $row["UserID"] . "<br>");
                    printf ("XP: " . thousandsCurrencyFormat($row["XP"]) . "<br>");
                    printf ("Level: " . $row["level"] . "<br>");
                    printf ("<br>");
                    printf ('</div">');
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }

            mysqli_close($db);
        ?>
    </div>
```

I expected the output to be 2 different div tags under eachother and not connected like they are now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your html tag in last div is wrong

```
printf ('</div">');
```

should be

```
printf ('</div>');
```